# Is Self essential in a method return?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, self

I wonder if there is a difference between :

```
def replace_title(new_title)
  new_title
end
```

And

```
def replace_title(new_title)
  self.title = new_title
end
```

I know there is difference between:`title = new_title`  that will create a local variable, but what will happen for the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the code will just return you the value of `new_title`

The code below will just return you the value of `new_title`

```
def replace_title(new_title)
  new_title
end
```

Whereas this code will just assign the `title` attribute with `new_title` and will return the value of `title` which is same as the value of `new_title`

```
def replace_title(new_title)
  self.title = new_title
end
```

But remember this will not save the value of object as you are not calling:

```
self.save
# or
save
```

As soon as you are out of the action the value will be reset to the previous value of `title`.

Answer (score 0):

With definition:

```
def replace_title(new_title)
  new_title
end
```

`replace_title("abc")` returns `"abc"`.

With definition:

```
def replace_title(new_title)
  self.title = new_title
end
```

`replace_title("abc")` is equivalent to `title=("abc")` (because `self.title = new_title` is equivalent to `title=(new_title)`). Assuming that `title=` is defined as:

```
def title=(new_title)
  @title = new_title
end
```

then `replace_title("abc")` returns `"abc"`, but also sets `@title` instance variable to `"abc"`.